# Material-ui v1 Safari iOS supports

Tags: material-ui

What about Safari iOS supports for matraial-ui v1? 
I try to migrate from v0 to v1 my App, and i have big problem with interface rendering.
Redrawing components is completely unpredictable. For the first time we Open the page-everything is terrible, each time in a different way. Re-open in the second time move to correct display. There is also the assumption that the problem occurs when you use MuiThemeProvider V0 and v1 together

IOS 11

Comment: It is possible to use MUI v0 and v1 alongside each other, but you have to be pretty careful about it. We are doing it in our app.

Is this only affecting the Safari in iOS and no other browsers?

Comment: Such problem i have only with safary mobile